# Getting same number when using Math.random() and ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble() and Random class nextDouble() method?

Tags: java, class, random

A BankApplication program in Java, problem in `setDebitCard()` function.

Here I am not able to generate a unique random number after every *java run* for `debitCardNumber` variable while it is working fine with `debitCardPin`.

I tried working with Random class method 
`nextDouble(),Math.random()`, `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble()` too..

Problems:

1. The `debitCardNumber` output is the same after trying everything mentioned above. (No syntax error whatsoever)
2. Also, I am getting the same 10 digits `debitCardNumber` instead of 12 digits.
3. `debitCardPin` is working fine, But Sometimes it gives me a unique 3 digit random number.

***CODE***

```
package bankAccountApp;

import java.util.Random;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Current extends Account {

    private int debitCardNumber;

    private int debitCardPin;

    Random rand = new Random();

//setDebitCard() code

private void setDebitCard(){

    debitCardNumber = (int)(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble()*Math.pow(10,12));


/* Also tried using

   debitCardNumber = (int)(rand.nextDouble()*Math.pow(10,12));

   debitCardNumber = (int)(Math.random()*Math.pow(10,12));

*/

    debitCardPin = (int)(Math.random()*Math.pow(10,4));
    }
```

Expected Result:

1. `debitCardNumber` should return a unique random 12 digit integer after every ***JAVA RUN***
2. `debitCardPin` should return only 4 digit integer.

Actual Result:

1. `debitCardNumber` returns same 10 digit integer after every ***JAVA RUN***
2. `debitCardPin` sometimes returns a 3 digit unique random integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies when you are down casting to an `int`, the maximum value an `int` can hold is `2147483647` which is of 10 digits so no way it can return you a number greater than that.

So you need to make the field `debitCardNumber` a `long`:

```
private long debitCardNumber;
```

Change the code to this for getting the 12 digit number:

```
long min = (long)Math.pow(10, 11);
long max = (long)Math.pow(10, 12);
long debitCardNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(min,  max);
```

And for the 4-digit `debitCardPin` :

```
int debitCardPin = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000, 10000);
```

There is no need to cast the numbers to `long` or `int` explicitly there are methods on the `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` which will give the respective type of numbers given the `min` and `max` value. Using this method you can be assured that you always get a value between the `min`(inclusive) and `max` (exclusive). That would resolve your problem of *"But Sometimes it gives me a unique 3 digit random number."*

Comment: Thank you very much @Amardeep Bhowmick  **IT WORKED**   .Don't you think we should write `max+1` in  `long debitCardNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(min,  max);`     Also still not getting why only `2147483647 ` was been repeated.It should have been any 10 digit `int<=2147483647 `.

Comment: @SohailShaikh no we don't need to write `max  +1` as the end number is exclusive so if I give 10000 it will only generate values upto 9999. You were getting the value `2147483647` always as the the 12 digit number you generated was down casted to an `int`, but the maximum possible value of int is `2147483647` so that was always the result the max value of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is int. It is too small (you have overflows here).

You could try following code:

```
double rndValue = (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble() * Math.pow(10, 12));
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##");
formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
String result = formatter.format(rndValue);
System.out.println(result);
```